# Non compliant RSU stocks as compensation

Tags: halal-haram, sharia

Assalmu alaikum,

I have a question regarding RSUs as compensation.
I work for an IT company which provides me the RSUs(Restricted stock Units) as part of compensation which are given to us over a period of 3 years.
So company decides a certain amount every year as part of appraisal compensation and they buy the RSUs with that amount and are vested to us 33% each year.
The company's major business revenue(~98-99%) is shariah compliant and the stock is non compliant according to many shariah stock screeners and is based on financials (not business revenue/activity), debt compliance to be specific. Hence I am confused if I should accept the stocks.
I read some opinions like

a) We can encash the stocks at earliest(after vested) and keep the actual amount awarded and give away the gains(at the time of selling).

b) Since the company's business is compliant and failing compliance only based on financials, we can hold the stock and sell it later as we like (as long as business revenue is compliant).

Please guide me as what is the right way. Jazakallah!